# Create endpoint using JSON-SERVER fake api to filter objects by tags

Tags: angular, json-server

Hello i have array of objects (db.json):

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "title": "jsovn-server",
  "answer": "typffficode",
  "subpoints": null,
  "tags": ["javascript", "typescript"],
  "image": "null"
},
{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "jsondsf-server",
  "answer": "typisdfcode",
  "subpoints": null,
  "tags": ["angular", "rxjs"],
  "image": null
}
```

I want to create endpoint with query param to filter object by tags. When user choose tag "angular" json-server should return me only second object. When user will choose javascript and rxjs tag json-server then return me two object.

How can I make such an endpoint?